# PowerBI - calculated field to check for dissimilar items in a semi-colon separated list in a row cell

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, calculated-field

I am using PowerBI desktop to create visualization from data source (a table in excel sheet) and I need to create a calculated field from one of the columns from the data. One of the columns in my data table is as follows:

| Technology |
| --- |
| A |
| A;A |
| B;B;B |
| C;D;C |
| A;A;B |
| B;B;B |
| D;D |
| A; |
| ; |
| ;; |

I want to create a new column of type Boolean that outputs 1 when only one unique item is in a row of column and 0 when items in the semi-colon separated list are not unique. Like this:

| Technology | New Column |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A;A | 1 |
| B;B;B | 1 |
| C;D;C | 0 |
| A;A;B | 0 |
| B;D;B | 0 |
| D;D | 1 |
| A; | 1 |
| ; | 0 |
| ;; | 0 |

How can I do this in PowerBI desktop?

EDIT: Updated requirements to test three more cases. (last three rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Add a new column and type in the following:

```
if List.Count( List.RemoveItems( List.Distinct( Text.Split([Technology],";")), {""})) = 1 then 1 else 0
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. `List.Count()` and `List.Distinct()` was what I was looking for.

Comment: I added three more rows to test different scenarios encountered in my data. Your proposed solution fails in these cases. Can the custom column formula check for `;` and determine if the list is empty?

Comment: Tried this custom formula and it seems to work: `if List.Contains(List.Distinct(Text.Split([Technology],";")),"") then if List.Count( List.Distinct( Text.Split([Technology],";"))) - 1 = 1 then 1 else 0 else if List.Count( List.Distinct( Text.Split([Technology],";"))) = 1 then 1 else 0` Wondering if there is a simpler/efficient if/else to check the conditions

Comment: I'll update the code now. Next time please include all your sample data in your original question and if you have a new question, mark this as solved and ask a new question. Thanks